# R - for loop - two columns whose values depend on each other

Tags: r

Apologies - I'm used to working with Excel/Minitab/SQL, where this kind of thing works differently.

I have an excel dataset with columns "Date" (Column "A"), "Pallets" (Column "B), "Lt" (Column "K") and "Tt" (Column "L"), where the values for column "Lt" and "Tt" depend on each other, and fixed parameters (alpha and beta), which are listed in cells in the spreadsheet ("T3" and "T4", respectively).

In Excel, I simply enter the formulae for Lt and Tt in cells "K6" and "L6" respectively and drag these down.  Excel then updates both columns simultaneously to reach the correct value.  The formulae are `=$T$3*K5+(1-$T$3)*(K5+L5)` and `=$T$4*(C6-C5)+(1-$T$4)*L5` respectively.

However, in R, I have tried updating the values of both columns using a for loop:

```
                for(i in 3:368)
            df[i,"Lt"]<-alpha*df[i-1,"Lt"]+(1-alpha)*(df[i-1,"Lt"]+df[i-1,"Tt"])
            for (i in 3:368)
            df[i,"Tt"]<-beta*(df[i,"Pallets"] - df[i-1,"Pallets"])+(1-beta)*df[i-1,"Tt"]
```

The problem with this is that this means that both columns change their values separately.  Consequently, they don't interact with each other as they update, so I end up with two not-quite correct columns.

The values of alpha and beta are 269 and 0.787890411 respectively.  In Excel, I get:

```
                Date    Pallets Lt  Tt
            01/01/2011  491     
            02/01/2011  385 269 0.79
            03/01/2011  662 269.7879    0.843133
            04/01/2011  28  270.6298    0.843133
            05/01/2011  46  271.4718    0.843132
            06/01/2011  403 272.3156    0.843132
            07/01/2011  282 273.1588    0.843133
            08/01/2011  315 274.0021    0.843133
```

Whereas with R, because the two columns don't update simultaneously, I get variously different values for Lt and Tt each time I update either column.  Currently I have:

```
                         Date Pallets       Lt        Tt
            1  28/12/2011     491       NA        NA
            2  29/12/2011     385 269.0000 0.7878904
            3  30/12/2011     662 269.7879 0.8431328
            4  31/12/2011      28 270.6310 0.7161642
            5  01/01/2012      46 271.3472 0.7196210
            6  02/01/2012     403 272.0668 0.7908770
            7  03/01/2012     282 272.8577 0.7665189
            8  04/01/2012     315 273.6242 0.7729656
            9  05/01/2012     327 274.3971 0.7752110
            10 06/01/2012     458 275.1724 0.8012559
```

How can I get both columns to update and reflect each other, as happens automatically in Minitab or Excel?

Comment: I would consider writing a function in R that you use to make updates to  columns and as part of its functionality updates the dependent columns as you desire.

In my experience R's intended use is for analyzing data retrospectively, and isn't commonly used for managing, writing and updating data outside of simulation.  That doesn't mean it can't be, but I think your best route is what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the `for` loops:

```
for(i in seq(3, nrow(df), by = 1)) {
  df[i,"Lt"]<-alpha*df[i-1,"Lt"]+(1-alpha)*(df[i-1,"Lt"]+df[i-1,"Tt"])
  df[i,"Tt"]<-beta*(df[i,"Pallets"] - df[i-1,"Pallets"])+(1-beta)*df[i-1,"Tt"]
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use hard-coded numbers for things like row counts.  Those can change, and it'd be a pain to constantly update the code when they do.